# Redux + React-router component not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

So I'm trying to configure `React-router` with `Redux` I've used [this example](https://github.com/rackt/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world) to setup a basic app.

When I try to render my components I get 1 error and 2 warnings.

The error is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined`.

Warning #1: `Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null or undefined. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).`

Warning #2: `Warning: Only functions or strings can be mounted as React components.`

I just got two simple component. A `Root` component and a `Container` component to test if things are working fine.

**Content of the Root component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createHistory } from 'history';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import timeline from '../reducers/timeline';

import Container from '../components/Container';

const store = createStore(combineReducers({timeline}));

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.info(store.getState());
})

const history = createHistory();

React.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    {() =>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={Container}/>
      </Router>
    }
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Content of the Container component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Container extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="outter">
        Container
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log(state);

  return {
    test: state,
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    type: 'TEST_ACTION',
  }
)(Container);
```

**Just in case - the content of the reducer as well:**

```
const initialState = [
  {id: 1, message: 'Test message'},
];

export default function timeline(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TEST_ACTION':
      return initialState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem I can see is in the second parameter you are passing to the `connect` function in the `Container` component. You are passing an object. According to [the documentation](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options), if you pass an object it will expect the properties of that object to be action creators (which are functions). So it might look something like this:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    test: () => { type: 'TEST_ACTION' }
  }
)(Container);
```

That will then add a property to your props called `test` which will be a function that you can call to dispatch the test action.