# Redux + React-Router doesn't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

So I have pretty standard code which is still doesn't work. What's wrong here?

I tried this solution as I have the same errors: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446173/redux-react-router-component-not-rendering), but of no success.
my errors in browser console still are:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components)

Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

My code is:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory');
var createStore = require('redux').createStore;
var Provider = require('react-redux');
var connect = require('react-redux').connect;

var options = 'someTxt';

var reducer = function (state = {}, action) {
    console.log('reducer was called with state', state, 'and action', action)
    return state;
};

const store = createStore(reducer, options);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {options: state.options};
};

var Index = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.options}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

connect(mapStateToProps, {
    test: () => { type: 'TEST_ACTION' }
})(Index);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        {() =>
            <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
                <Route path="/" component={Index}/>
            </Router>}
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("container")
);
```

__________UPDATE__________
Please also read comments, there are really useful information

Comment: If you are using React > 0.14 you shouldn't have to use the `{() => }` wrapper anymore.

Comment: You are right, I already stumbled upon it and got to the same

Comment: @Mike I have no errors, but `this.props.options` is still undefined

Comment: With this line: `const store = createStore(reducer, options);` you are setting the store to be equal to 'someTxt'. You'd need to add curly braces if using ES6 (`createStore(reducer, {options})`) or the correct object key in < ES6 (`createStore(reducer, {options: options})`)

Comment: @Mike Now I see in console: `reducer was called with state Object {options: "someTxt"} and action Object {type: "@@redux/INIT"}` before it was just 'someTxt', not Object. But the whole code still doesn't work. I changed `function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log("mapStateToProps ",state);
    return {options: state.options};
};`, and I don't see it in the console, so this part is not even evaluated.

Comment: Ah hah, I think I see the issue. You are calling `connect()` without assigning it to anything. Rename `Index` to `IndexContainer` and then do `var Index = connect(mapStateToProps)(IndexContainer);`. Keep `component={Index}` in the `<Route/>` though.

Comment: It works now, I really appreciate you help!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Comment: @Mike Probably you'd be interested to take part in this this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33839709/dispatchaction-changes-the-store-state-but-component-is-not-updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Provider` is part of the `react-redux` module; not all of it.

You need to change your require statement from

```
var Provider = require('react-redux');
```

to

```
var Provider = require('react-redux').Provider;
```

or with ES6 module syntax

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I mean, now errors completely changed )

Answer (score 0):

When you use arrow functions with bracets it's not the same that your function returns object. The bracets means function body (so you must use return statement in it). Here is how it suppose to be:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, {
    test: () => {return { type: 'TEST_ACTION' }}
})(Index);
```

Comment: I believe the correct syntax is `test: () => ({type: 'TEST_ACTION'})`, but I could be wrong.