# Dispatch(action) changes the store state but component is not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I have pretty simple code, the idea is to fetch some data via ajax and make them available for the whole life of app. I need it this way because I use the Index component in many places, and I cannot afford fetch the data each time I render it.
I see via all that messages in console, that the data I need is fetched and the store.state is updated and I see there all data I need, but Index component is never updated, and I don't get this data inside it.
I am a novice, so probably I'm just blind to something stupid...
I'd also appreciate any piece of advise regarding the whole architecture for my problem.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory');
var createStore = require('redux').createStore;
var Provider = require('react-redux').Provider;
var connect = require('react-redux').connect;

window.onload=setOptions;

var options = [];
var setOptReducer = function (state = [], action) {
    console.log('setOptReducer was called with state', state, 'and action', action)
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_ITEM':
            return [
                ...state,
                action.data
            ]
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

var setOptCreator = function (options) {
    console.log("options inside setOptCreator ", options);
    return {
        type: 'ADD_ITEM',
        data: options
    }
};

var optDispatcher = function(options) {
    store.dispatch(setOptCreator(options));
};

const store = createStore(setOptReducer, options);

function setOptions() {
    loadFromServer(optDispatcher);
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log("mapStateToProps ",state);
    return {options: state.options};
};

var IndexContainer = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                {console.log("Index rendered with options ", this.props.options)}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

function loadFromServer(callback) {
    function option(value, label) {
        this.value = value;
        this.label = label;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var options = [];
            {.....put some elements from data to options}
            console.log("options inside loadFromServer is ", options);
            callback(options);
            console.log('store state after callback:', store.getState());
        }.bind(this)
    });
};

var Index = connect(mapStateToProps)(IndexContainer);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
                <Route path="/" component={Index}/>
            </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically in your mapStateToProps, you have `options: state.options;` but right now there is no thing *named* as options in the state. From the docs http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html, when you use `createStore` passing in `setOptReducer` as argument, it creates a store with just one reducer and as a result `state` on it's own is the value of the store.

Could you try changing your `mapStateToProps` to this?

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log("mapStateToProps ",state);
    return {options: state};
};
```

If this works, then you could rename some things, since right now it might be confusing. For example removing `var options = []` and change the reducer function to options and have

```
const store = createStore(options, []);
```

It is recommended to use `combineReducers` to create a single root reducer out of many - and if you pass that to `createStore`, then the state is an object, and you can then do `state.setOptReducer`

Hope it's not too confusing

Comment: Hello, no, it didn't make any change. If it helps, I have in console: itemsReducer was called with state [] and action Object {type: "@@redux/INIT"}
mapStateToProps  []
Index rendered with options  undefined
mapStateToProps  []
optionsReg inside loadFromServer is  [option, option, option]
optionsReg inside setOptCreator  [option, option, option]
itemsReducer was called with state [] and action Object {type: "ADD_ITEM", data: Array[305]}
mapStateToProps  [Array[305]store state after callback: [Array[305]]

Comment: I'm running your code now, it seems that if you do  return {options: state}; in the mapState function, this will make the index update, but I'm still checking why it wasn't working before

Comment: Thanks to you I got to the problem, now I completely understand it. I put it as a separate answer as I believe it could help some novice like me ))

Comment: I would definitely take the time to read through the entire [Redux Docs](http://redux.js.org/). There are a lot of really great patterns and ideas in there that might help answer your questions. Dan did a great job writing it and going step by step so it's easy to understand. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

Finally with huge help of luanped I got to the root of the problem, and I believe it worth putting as a separate answer.

`mapStateToProps` really cannot map `state.options` to `options` as the `state` doesn't contain `options` attribute, because in the `setOptReducer` `actionData` is being saved by concatenating it to the `state` array, not by putting as a separate named attribute of object `state`:

```
   case 'ADD_ITEM':
        return [
            ...state,
            action.data
        ]
```

So `mapStateToProps` doesn't really changes `options` (change is `undefined` to `undefined`) and that's why the component doesn't re-render.
So the decision is to expose the whole `state` as `options`, which is changing this.props of the component, so it works.
To make it work the more correct way, without exposing the whole `state` to the component, but just the `options` part, reducer's code should be:

```
    return {
        ...state,
        options: action.data
    }
```

This way `state` becomes to have `options` attribute, `mapStateToProps` sees it and the component re-renders.